# Disable Button If Not Match Username

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Currently I use `jquery` **.keyup** function to check if has started to type in the input field. And then it enabled button. Else if no text in input disables button.

**Question:**

Instead of **keyup** function I would like to be able to make the **button disabled** if the text that entered in the input is typed doesn't match this `$user['username']`

And then if text that is entered is matches then enable button

**Input Field**

```
<input type="text" id="input-user-<?php echo $user['username']; ?>" name="username" value="" class="form-control input-user" />
```

**Script**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#button-delete-user-<?php echo $user['username']; ?>').attr('disabled', true);

    $('#input-user-<?php echo $user['username']; ?>').keyup(function(){

        if($(this).val().length !=0)

        $('#button-delete-user-<?php echo $user['username']; ?>').attr('disabled', false);            

        else

        $('#button-delete-user-<?php echo $user['username']; ?>').attr('disabled', true);
    });
});
</script>
```

**View**

```
<?php if ($users) { ?>
<?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-<?php echo $user['username']; ?>">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header clearfix">
            <div class="pull-left">
            <h2 style="font-size: 18px;">Are you absolutely sure?</h2></div>
            <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="alert alert-warning text-center">
                Unexpected bad things will happen if you don't read this! 
            </div>
            <p class="text-center">If you delete this user, this user will not be able to login to the admin,
            and all of his or her user information will be <b>Removed For Ever!</b>
            </p>
            <br/>
            <p class="text-center">Please type in the username of the user to confirm.</p>
            <p class='error_msg'></p>
            <form role="form" action="<?php echo $action;?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_id">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="input-user-<?php echo $user['username']; ?>" name="username" value="" class="form-control input-user" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user['user_id']; ?>" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <button type="submit" id="button-delete-user-<?php echo $user['username']; ?>" class="btn btn-user-delete"><span class="text-danger">I understand the consequences, deleting this user</span></button>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#button-delete-user-<?php echo $user['username']; ?>').attr('disabled', true);

    $('#input-user-<?php echo $user['username']; ?>').keyup(function(){

        if($(this).val().length !=0)

        $('#button-delete-user-<?php echo $user['username']; ?>').attr('disabled', false);            

        else

        $('#button-delete-user-<?php echo $user['username']; ?>').attr('disabled', true);
    });
});
</script>
<?php }?>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: It is a bit confusing why you have a foreach loop? Are you actually rendering all this HTML per user?

Comment: I use codeigniter for my php side of things so to display all users in the table list just above the foreach. I need foreach, and having the foreach like that for modal works better.

Comment: Duplicating the same HTML over and over again is not good. You should refactor to have only one modal that works dynamically depending on which delete button is clicked.

Comment: Great advice will work in it cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
$(function() {
    $('.someInput').on('keyup',function() {
        var username = "test";
        if( $(this).val() == username ) {
            $('.someButton').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        else {
            $('.someButton').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/t678vbb8/)

## EDIT

You can implement it in your script like this:

```
<?php if ($users) { ?>
<?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>

            ....

            <form role="form" action="<?php echo $action;?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_id">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="input-user" data-username="<?php echo $user['username']; ?>" name="username" value="" class="form-control input-user" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user['user_id']; ?>" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="button-delete-user" data-username="<?php echo $user['username']; ?>" class="btn btn-user-delete"><span class="text-danger">I understand the consequences, deleting this user</span></button>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

```
$(function() {
    $('button.button-delete-user').attr('disabled', true);
    $('.input-user').on('keyup',function() {
        var username = $(this).data('username');
        if( $(this).val() == username ) {
            $('button[data-username="'+username+'"]').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        else {
            $('button[data-username="'+username+'"]').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/t678vbb8/1/)

Comment: Doesn't really work with the `foreach` approach that the OP seems to be using

Comment: @LinkinTED Your code that you just removed worked perfect you could re show your code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Working example

```js
$("#input-user").keyup(function(){
  console.log($(this).val(), $(this).data("name"));
  if($(this).val() == $(this).data("name"))    
    $("#button-delete-user").prop('disabled', false);
  else
    $("#button-delete-user").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="input-user" data-name="username" name="username" value="" class="form-control input-user" />
  <button type="submit" id="button-delete-user" class="btn btn-user-delete" disabled>GO</button>
</form>
```